# Using SignalR and jquery to change css on a span

Tags: jquery, html, css, razor, signalr

I'm using SignalR to update this span that is changing color based on a real time source. The connection works fine, but I have some trouble with the update part of the css classes on the span.

Problem is that when I need to update several classes on one element, the class names just get appended and not changed.
Here's my markup:

```
<span id="activity-@UnitId" class="badge sl-badge-normal connection-false">
    <i id="asxConnected-@UnitId" class="fa fa-rss"></i>
    <span id="activityMessage-@UnitId">
        @Model.ActivityMessage    
    </span>
</span>
```

In the outer span the classes `sl-badge-normal` and `connection-false` are the classes that needs to be changed.
`sl-badge-normal` can be the following values:

- sl-badge-ok
- sl-badge-warning
- sl-badge-error
- sl-badge-normal

and connection-false can only change between that and connection-true.

Before you ask, yes, the two needs to be separated into two different jquery-updates as it's completely different messages :)
My jquery looks like this for the connection part:

```
messageHub.client.notifyAlive = function (aliveMessage, unitId) {
    if (aliveMessage) {
        $('#activity-' + unitId).addClass("connection-true");
    } else {
        $('#activity-' + unitId).addClass("connection-false");
    }
};
```

And for the badge part it looks like this:

```
messageHub.client.notifyActivityStatus = function(statusColor, statusText, unitId) {
    $('#activity-' + unitId).addClass("badge " + statusColor);
    $('#activityMessage-' + unitId).text(statusText);
};
```

My problem here being that the following statement will go from this:

```
<span id="activity-@UnitId" class="badge sl-badge-normal connection-false">
```

to this:

```
<span id="activity-@UnitId" class="badge sl-badge-normal connection-false sl-badge-error connection-true">
```

Could anyone please suggest a solution for this? Is posting the entire class string neccesary each time there's an update or can I simply swap single class names?

Comment: Don't use mutually exclusive CSS classes. If `connection-false` is the base state, just drop that class entirely. Add `connection-true` to indicate a change from the base state. Remove `connection-true` to indicate return to the base state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a lot of technologies here. Have you considered something like knockout?

Here is a short example how to do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
  .badge { border-width: 3px; }

  .sl-badge-normal { border-color: black; }
  .sl-badge-ok { border-color: green; }
  .sl-badge-warning { border-color: yellow; }
  .sl-badge-error { border-color: red; }

  .connection-true { border-style: solid; }
  .connection-false { border-style: dashed; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <span class="badge" data-bind="css: badgeClass">
  <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
  <span data-bind="text: activityMessage"></span>
 </span>

 <button data-bind="click: toggleConnection">connection</button>
 <button data-bind="click: toggleStatus">status</button>

 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.0.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

 <script>
  var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.connected = ko.observable(true);
    self.status = ko.observable(0);
    self.activityMessage = ko.observable('activity message');

    self.onlineClass = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.connected() ? 'connection-true' : 'connection-false';
    });

    self.statusClass = ko.computed(function(){
      var statusClasses = ['sl-badge-normal','sl-badge-ok','sl-badge-warning','sl-badge-error'];

      return statusClasses[self.status()];
    });

    self.badgeClass = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.onlineClass() + ' ' + self.statusClass();
    });

    // test ...     

    self.toggleConnection = function(){
      self.connected(!self.connected());
    };

    self.toggleStatus = function(){
      self.status((self.status() + 1) % 4);
    };
 };

 $(function(){
  ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use toggleClass to remove/add a class based on boolean.

```
messageHub.client.notifyAlive = function (aliveMessage, unitId) {
       $('#activity-' + unitId).toggleClass("connection-true",aliveMessage).toggleClass("connection-false", !aliveMessage);
```

};